# Windows 2008 /IIS7 seting up webhits

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We are able to run successfully webhits.dllon Widnows 2003/IIS 6 to get the highlighting works. But we are not able to setting it up on windows 2008 IIS7. When we tried to create new handler mapping with

```
C:\Windows\System32\WEBHITS.DLL
```

getting the following error

> The executable specified for the
>   IsapiModule should be a.dll file.

But it is a dll file.

Does anybody able to setup WebHits.dll successfully on IIS7 please share their experience.
Thank you for in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kazim-

In Server 2008, the hit-highlighting is incorporated automatically by installing the index service when IIS is installed. As indicated by Method 2 at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328832, you should ensure that Indexing Service is set to "Allowed" under "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" in the IIS Manager.